# Building a camera transition for switching rooms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a Zelda type camera that changes position after you reach a trigger point.

this is the code for the camera movement

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform target;
  public float smoothing;
  public Vector2 maxPosition;
  public Vector2 minPosition;

  void LateUpdate()
  {
      if (transform.position != target.position)
      {
          Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, transform.position.z);
          targetPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, minPosition.x, maxPosition.x);
          targetPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.y, minPosition.y, maxPosition.y);
          transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, smoothing);

      }
  }
}
```

and this is the code for the room transition

```
public class RoomMove : MonoBehaviour
{

  public Vector2 cameraChange;
  public Vector3 playerChange;
  private CameraMovement cam;



  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
      cam = Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraMovement> ();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {

  }

  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
  {
      if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
      {
          cam.minPosition += cameraChange;
          cam.maxPosition += cameraChange;
          other.transform.position += playerChange;
      }
  }
}
```

I've already tried to look up the answer in google and I found something similar but it did not work for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) . Remember, SO is not a code writing service. You are expected to provide a clear description of your goal and what errors you are encountering, otherwise it's almost impossible to help

Comment: Does your RoomMove game object have a Collider attached?

Comment: Could you please provide info on what is currently happening? Any errors? What behaviour is expected vs returned?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little difficult due to the lack of details, info, and desire.
First make sure your setup is correct.

- Does the object with `RoomMove` on it have a 2D collider marked trigger?
- Does player have the "Player" tag on it?
- Does the main camera have the movement script with the target variable set to the instance of the player? (Not a prefab, from the hierarchy)

Double check all of these first.

What you have here leads me to believe that all of your levels are side by side in one scene correct?
You could try removing the clamping and simply give each room an empty transform in the middle and when you hit the transition change the camera's target.